# Map crashes in Nexus 5X API 28 but runs perfectly fine in Google PIXEL 2 XL API 27

Tags: java, android, exception, google-maps-android-api-2, android-9.0-pie

I have followed the Google Developer's Guide to create a map activity using Google Map's API. My API key is already activated, so what's the cause of the crash in Nexus 5X.

Sharing my AndroidManifest.xml,MapActivity.java,google_maps_api.xml,activitymaps.xml and Gradle module:-

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kiit.mapone">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
package com.example.kiit.mapone;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

**google_maps_api.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">KEY IS HERE</string>
</resources>
```

*I have replaced my API key with "KEY IS HERE" in this file due to security reasons*

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kiit.mapone"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**Logcat(errors):**

```
2018-12-18 10:06:42.509 27581-27610/com.example.kiit.mapone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5
    Process: com.example.kiit.mapone, PID: 27581
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
        at ez.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):3)
        at ey.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):3)
        at fa.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):15)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.al.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):6)
        at ed.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):21)
        at ed.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):8)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000d/MapsDynamite.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000d/MapsDynamite.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at ad.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):4)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at ez.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):3) 
        at ey.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):3) 
        at fa.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):15) 
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.al.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):6) 
        at ed.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):21) 
        at ed.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@14799084@14.7.99 (100700-223214910):8) 
2018-12-18 10:06:42.660 27581-27581/com.example.kiit.mapone E/SchedPolicy: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: where is your Crashlog?? Have a look **[Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)**

Comment: why am I getting an error when I use this workaround <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" /> in the <application> of my Androidmanifest.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in your manifest inside `<application>`

```
<uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
```

**EDIT**

Your application tag should look like this

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />

</application>
```

Comment: I am getting an error that <uses-library> element must be a direct child of <application> element

Comment: That's what i told you. Put it inside `application` tag

Comment: I did what you asked and ran the app in Nexus 5X and the build failed with the error    Element type "application" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: Check my edited answer. You wrote same?

Comment: Thanks i get it now,my mistake was that I was placing it inside the first part of the application tag.